# how to set :module_headers in podspec dependency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a podspec that contains dependencies like this

```
  s.dependency "React-Core"
  s.dependency "AWSCore", '2.9.8'
  s.dependency "AWSLogs", '2.9.8'
  s.dependency "BCryptSwift", '1.1'
  s.dependency "CryptoSwift", '1.0'
  s.dependency "JWTDecode", '2.6'
  s.dependency "MQTTClient", '0.15.2'
  s.dependency "MQTTClient/Websocket", '0.15.2'
  s.dependency "ObjcExceptionBridging", '1.0.1'
  s.dependency "OpenSSL-Universal", '1.1.1100'
  s.dependency "ReachabilitySwift", '5.0.0'
  s.dependency "SocketRocket", '0.5.1'
  s.dependency "SwiftSocket", '2.0.2'
  s.dependency "XCGLogger", '7.0.0'
```

It gives me this error

```
[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `XCGLogger` depends upon `ObjcExceptionBridging`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

The Swift pod `openpath-reactnative` depends upon `AWSCore`, `AWSLogs`, `MQTTClient`, and `SocketRocket`, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
```

How to set :module_headers in a podspec dependency?

when i tried this

```
s.dependency "ObjcExceptionBridging", '1.0.1', :modular_headers => true
```

gives me this error

```
Invalid `openpath-reactnative.podspec` file: [!] Unsupported version requirements. ["1.0.1", {:modular_headers=>true}] is not valid..
```

Answer (score 1):

reference https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.5.0/

```
spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself, and I can't remember how I figured out the fix, but here it is:

You need to put it in the root pod file, not the podspec.

i.e. where your

`Pod 'ObjcExceptionBridging'`

is, needs to become

`Pod 'ObjcExceptionBridging', :modular_headers => true`

Hope this helps! :)

(And at the very least it'll be here if someone comes searching)

Comment: thank you but, this is for a library creation, so the change need to be made in podspec and not podfile